# Regarding the participants of hyperledger Fabric Network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I need a clarity regarding the participants of network if i created a participant using the command ( composer participant add -c anitha@sample-network -d '{"$class":"test.participant","name":"Anitha","id":"1"}' ) and issued the identity using the command ( composer identity issue -c anitha@sample-network -f user.card -u user -a "resource:test.participant#1") Now my question is this user is the participant of network belonging to ORG1 or not specific about ORG1. How can we know that he is participant of org1 in the permisssion.acl file so that i can have seperate access permissions to participants of different orgs

Answer (score 0):

based on the info you provided above - a rule to only allow the current participant to update other participants (in the same class) that are in the same org - ie org1 - would be:

```
rule myACLrule {
    description: "check which target participants THIS current participant can update"
    participant(p): "test.participantMember"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "test.participantMember"
    condition: ( (p.name.lastIndexOf('org1',4) > -1) == (r.name.lastIndexOf('org1',4) > -1) )
    action: ALLOW
}
```

where '4' is the length of your org substring eg. 'org1' etc.

ps. `participant` is already a reserved word for different purposes in the model file, so hence the example uses `participantMember` for clarity.

pps, if you had different org names - just use `indexOf()` - examples a-plenty by searching on Google (other search engines are available).

Comment: sorry actually anitha-org1 just i have kept its not mandatrory i can just have name as Anitha